# Find character in string in Ada

Tags: ada

Is there a simple way of checking whether a given character is in a string?
I know that if the string was simply a range (say `'a'..'z'`) then I could have used the `in` operator, but I need something to the lines of `char in "- _,."`. What's the best way of doing so in Ada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "Is_In" from the [Ada.Strings.Maps](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-2.html) package.